# how add loading dialog in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, progressdialog

I am trying to add Loading dialog when my app load data json url because shows blank screen until data comes when lunching app

Here is the code

```
inner class Dep : AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){


        //        for build connection
        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String{

            var text : String
            val connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

            try {
                connection.connect()
                text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use{reader -> reader.readText()} }


            } finally{

                connection.disconnect()

            }
            return text
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

            val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(Context,this@MainActivity)
            progressDialog.setMessage("loading")
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
            progressDialog.show()

            super.onPostExecute(result)
            handleJson(result)

            if (progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        private fun handleJson (jsonString: String?){

            val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonString)
            val result = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result")
            val response = result.getJSONObject("response")
            val airport = response.getJSONObject("airport")
            val pluginData = airport.getJSONObject("pluginData")
            val schedule = pluginData.getJSONObject("schedule")
            val arrivals = schedule.getJSONObject("departures")
//        val data = arrivals.getJSONObject("data")
            val jsonArray = JSONArray(arrivals.get("data").toString())

            val list =  ArrayList<FlightShdu>()
            var x = 0
            while (x < jsonArray.length()){

                val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)



                list.add(FlightShdu(

                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("identification").getJSONObject("number").getString("default"),
                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airline").getString("name"),
                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("status").getString("text"),
                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("airline").getJSONObject("code").getString("icao"),
                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("flight").getJSONObject("time").getJSONObject("scheduled").getString("departure")


                    ))


                x++
            }
            list.forEach(::println)

            val adapter = ListAdapte(this@MainActivity,list)
            flight_dep_list.adapter = adapter

        }

        //    for get items from json api
        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {

        }


    }
```

l  used progress dialog code in `onPostExecute`

```
 override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(Context,this@MainActivity)
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading")
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
        progressDialog.show()

        super.onPostExecute(result)
        handleJson(result)

        if (progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

l got red line error

`classifier 'Context' dose not have a companion object , and  thus must be initialized here`

do l need add progress dialog xml ?

Comment: You should declare the ProgressDialog under your inner class. Then istanciate the Dialog under onBeforeExecute() and show it. Hide it under onPostExecuteFunction (showing the dialog in on post execute is too late)

Comment: progressdialog is deprecated, use progressbar instead

Comment: can you give me example please 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instance of Context like this lateinit var context2 : Context and then context2 = container!!.context in your activity or Fragment method and just pass context2 with ProgressDialog